# How to run a .exe from MSDN to download the software-fix from Wine?

Tags: windows, wine, executable

I had dual boot of windows 7 and ubuntu 10.10. Unfortunately my windows 7 crashed and I am trying to download the software from msdn using linux.

The problem is that i downloaded the exe that they send for the downloading purposes but even after installing wine the download does not progresses.

Is there any other way i can run that exe to download the software ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: this may be worth migrating over to SU - there are solutions to downloading Windows when you don't have a working Windows install, but they aren't really on topic for askubuntu, and you might get a better result over there.

Comment: From what I can tell this user is trying to download software from the Microsoft Developer Network and install it in Wine. Not downloading Windows. From what I can tell this question is still on topic, though a very thin line.

Comment: It's possible, but I disagree. It sounds more like the OP is attempting to download the Windows 7 installation media from MSDN in order to fix his Windows 7 installation. Microsoft (in their infinite wisdom) decided to allow the user to download an EXE, which in turn will download the ISO file from them.

Answer (score 0):

sould download iexplorers:
http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Installation:Ubuntu